# Laravel custom blade routing problems

Tags: php, laravel

first of all, I'm totally green at using laravel, so bear with me please :)
Thing is, I am trying to add a new blade routing to the routes.php file, the basic stuff I guess.

For example:

```
Route::get('testing', array('as' => 'testing', function()
    {
        return View::make('testing');
    }));
```

After saving, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException' with message 'No query results for model [App\Models\Page].' in /var/www/htdocs/myappname/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:126 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/htdocs/myappname/app/Models/Page.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail() 
#1 [internal function]: App\Models\Page->scopeFindByReference(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'testing') 
#2 /var/www/htdocs/myappname/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(834): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#3 /var/www/htdocs/myappname/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(915): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->callScope('scopeFindByRefe...', Array) 
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('findByReference', Array) 
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->findByReference('testing') in /var/www/htdocs/myappname/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 126
```

In the routes.php there is something like this, but it does not load up the blade, instead it loads a page created in the cms that has a slug testing. If I delete that page or rename it, regular 404 error pops up.

```
 if ($page->slug == 'testing') {
            $page->view = 'testing_homebld';
        }
```

Don't know what else to do since the app dev did not leave any documentation.

Thanks for the help gals and guys!

Comment: why not use Route::get('testing', function(){return View::make('testing');}); ?

Comment: The error says it cannot find a Page model. Is your application trying to create an instance of one somewhere (in the view, or ideally the controller)? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Hello,
if I use that I get this error:
Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in /var/www/htdocs/myappname/routes.php on line 201 
Really strange. :/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a routing clash.  The `if ($page->slug == 'testing') {` code is probably in a PageController.php controller, I think (not routes.php as you state); the error msg also describes the Page model.  That suggests some other routing is handling your request, not your testing route.

My guess is you have something like this in routes.php, which is catching your request to `http://your-site/testing` (controller name and method obviously could be anything in your code):

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@page');
```

This would match and handle a request to `http://your-site/testing`.

Your new testing route probably appears *after* this page route, which means it is ignored - the first route to match takes precedence and subsequent matches are ignored.

The quickest fix is to just move your new testing route *above* the conflicting page route, so it will take precedence.

Comment: Hey, 
if I add the code above I get this error:

 Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in /var/www/htdocs/myappname/routes.php on line 201

Really strange things are happening, guess I have to keep on digging though the files, and find out what the heck is going on. 

Appreciate all the answers!

Comment: Add what code?  All I suggested was moving your existing code in the routes file.